# $n$th term of the series 4, 32, 144........

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to put a formula for the $n$th term is this series.
$$
\begin{align}
t_{1} = 4\\
t_{2} = 32\\
t_{3} = 144\\
t_{4} = 512\\
t_{5} = 1600\\
t_{6} = 4608\\
t_{7} = 12544
\end{align}
$$
I first tried using interpolation, to see if there was any pattern but I got nothing, I also tried diving through by 4, looking at the new series I was thinking I'll get a formula in the form $t_{n} = 2^A+2^B$.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{t_{1}}{4} = 1\\
\frac{t_{2}}{4} = 8\\
\frac{t_{3}}{4} = 36\\
\frac{t_{4}}{4} = 128\\
\frac{t_{5}}{4} = 400\\
\frac{t_{6}}{4} = 1152\\
\frac{t_{7}}{4} = 3136
\end{align}
$$.
but still I got no formula for the $n$th term, please if anyone can help I'll be grateful.
Thanks

Comment: Where does the series come from? There are infinitelly many formulas that can fit the $7$ points you list....

Comment: Also, how is $\frac{t_7}{4}=3136$ if $t_7=2544$?!

Comment: $t_7=12544$. Makes it easier.

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C8%2C36%2C128%2C400%2C+1152%2C3136&sort=&language=english&go=Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After also dividing each series by $n^2$, as suggested by $@Claude Leibovici$.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{t_{1}}{4*1} = 1\\
\frac{t_{2}}{4*2^2} = 2\\
\frac{t_{3}}{4*3^2} = 4\\
\frac{t_{4}}{4*4^2} = 8\\
\frac{t_{5}}{4*5^2} = 16\\
\frac{t_{6}}{4*6^2} = 32\\
\frac{t_{7}}{4*7^2} = 64
\end{align}
$$.
I can clearly see the series formula is.
$$
t_{n} = 4×n^2×2^{n-1}
$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

What you did is good. Try now dividing $\frac{t_n}4$ by $n^2$.

Your turn and ... let me know.